# How to copy a files to a particular dir using ant?

Tags: ant

i need to copy test.bat into the bin folder
i worte a code in build.xml such that it should copy a file from bin/test.bat to dist/intall/windows/
but it not copying

project structure

project

|-dist-install-windows-bin

|-etc-bin-test.bat

|-src-build.xml

```
<target name="copy">
        <copy todir="./dist/install/windows/bin">
           <fileset dir=".">
               <include name="etc/bin/test.bat"/>                  
            </fileset>
        </copy>      
</target>
```

Comment: Did you try running it? what is the error(if any?)

Comment: i tried it its not copying into that specified location i dont knw y its not copying.i tried in this way also <copy todir="./dist/install/windows/bin">
      <fileset file="**/etc/bin/test.bat" />
</copy>

Comment: what is basedir of your build.xml?  The dir set will be relative to it.  In any case try with ant -debug.  It will give some clues what is wrong with pattern or dir.

Comment: my base dir of build is src, can you please tell me how i can go specify path for etc dir in build file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give parent directory as "dir" attribute

```
        <fileset dir="..">
           <include name="etc/bin/test.bat"/>                  
        </fileset>
```

Comment: can you please tell me do i need to specify .. in to copy directory instead of ..